# Log4J2 - Logging not occurring when run from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, log4j2

```
Eclipse: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Java: 1.8.0_201
Log4J2: whatever is pulled in by spring-boot-starter-log4j2 - might be 2.11.2 (mvn dependency:tree)
Spring Boot: 2.1.6.RELEASE
```

I have a set of Spring Boot services that use Log4J2 for logging purposes. The logging is set up for two captures: 1) console output to a text log file and 2) output produced by a specific class to report statistics to a separate JSON file.

When I execute the services by means of a launch script (on Linux), the outputs are properly written to their respective files. However, when I attempt to run a service from within eclipse (for development test/debug and bug fixes), the output always appears in the console. No files are ever produced. I've tried a number of things but nothing changes.

What I see in the console seems to indicate that, if anything, Log4J2 is *not* being used for logging, but instead that Logback *is*. I have excluded Logback in the POM files, but it's somehow still being used.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/JO24447/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/JO24447/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2020-03-10 09:06:48.489  INFO 8204 --- [           main] e.m.l.m.s.r.ApplicationMain              : Starting ApplicationMain on 532064-MITLL with PID 8204 (C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\REST_RST_Service\mission-services\route-generator\target\classes started by JO24447 in C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\REST_RST_Service\mission-services\route-generator)
2020-03-10 09:06:48.491  INFO 8204 --- [           main] e.m.l.m.s.r.ApplicationMain              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
...
```

Does anyone have ideas on what needs to be done to get eclipse to not use Logback and instead use Log4J2?

Here is the dependencies section of the parent POM file:

```
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` to check what library is using logback and the use the respective exclude

Comment: I did that already. It doesn't show up in the tree.

Comment: How your Maven POM or Gradle script (just the dependencies section) looks like? The application must behave the same, otherwise that "launch script" in Linux is adding/removing _something_ you are not aware of. Also, where do you have the configuration file for Log4J `2.x`?

Comment: src/main/resources/log4j2-spring.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following things

1. if you have excluded the spring-boot-starter-logging in your pom.
2. In case you are seeing that multiple bindings are present in the console, verify from which projects is it coming. (In my case, I was having a dependent project which was leading to duplicate dependencies).
3. Check Referenced libraries in eclipse for any duplicate jar references. You may see that multiple JARs showing are present. You can remove unwanted references.